# generalized estimating equations in survey package

Tags: r, survey

Is it possible to conduct generalized estimating equations in survery package ? If not how can I perform generalized estimating equations with wighted survey data ?

I did search the CRAN file of survey package and it is possible to perofrm GLMM but there is no information about GEE.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to do GLMM. Whether it's possible to do GEE depends on exactly what you mean.  If you are happy with the independence working model, you can just use `svyglm`. It gives you generalised linear models with robust standard errors.